# $\forall x \in \Bbb Q, \exists y \in \Bbb Q$ so that $x + y \in \Bbb Z $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\Bbb Q$ be set of all rational numbers.
Proof:

$\forall x \in \Bbb Q, \exists y \in \Bbb Q$ so that $x + y \in \Bbb Z $

This statement is true. Here is a proof:

Suppose $x$ is some rational number. We want to prove that there is a $y \in \Bbb Q$ such that $x + y \in \Bbb Z$. Since $x \in \Bbb Q$, that is, $x = a / b$ for some $a, b \in \Bbb Z$. and $b \neq 0$.

Let $y = 1 - (a/b)$, then, $y$ is a rational number. And $x + y$ = $(a/b) + 1 - (a/b) = 1 \in \Bbb Z$. End of proof.

Is this correct?

How about this one:

Let $\Bbb Q$ be set of all rational numbers.
Proof:

$\forall a \in \Bbb Q, \exists b \in \Bbb Q$ so that $a + b \notin \Bbb Z $

This statement is true. Here is a proof:

Suppose $a$ is some rational number. We want to prove that there is a $b \in \Bbb Q$ such that $a + b \notin \Bbb Z$. Since $a \in \Bbb Q$, that is, $a = n / m$ for some $n, m \in \Bbb Z$. and $m \neq 0$.

Let $b = 0$, then, $b$ is a rational number. And $a + b$ = $(a/b) + 0 = a/b \notin \Bbb Z$. End of proof.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ meant to be $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Looks good. ${}{}$

Comment: The question is it correct?

Comment: @peterwhy, Samim used the proof-strategy tag. I suppose they just want to know if their proof is valid.

Comment: Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $x = a/b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b \neq 0$ and $(a,b) = 1$. But $y := \frac{b-a}{b}$ is a desired choice, since $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x+y = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

First proof is correct. Second proof is incorrect it fails for a=1/1. Try adapting the technique you used for the first question to the second.